# Why my entities ids change before update?

Tags: java, crud, setter

I'm trying to update some entities, but their ids simply change even after setting the DTO's (and correct!) value.

On my method, I have the following:

```
    System.out.println("before -     parameterPojo.getId(): " + parameterPojo.getId());
    System.out.println("before -  parameterPojo.getFtpId(): " + parameterPojo.getFtpId());
    System.out.println("before -  parameterPojo.getSqlId(): " + parameterPojo.getSqlId());
    System.out.println("before - parameterPojo.getSmtpId(): " + parameterPojo.getSmtpId());

    Parameter parameter = populateParameterFromPojo(parameterPojo);

    System.out.println("after -     parameter.getId(): " + parameter.getId());
    System.out.println("after -  parameter.getFtpId(): " + parameter.getFtpConnection().getId());
    System.out.println("after -  parameter.getSqlId(): " + parameter.getSqlConnection().getId());
    System.out.println("after - parameter.getSmtpId(): " + parameter.getSmtpConnection().getId());
```

Where `parameterPojo` is the data transfer object and `parameter` is the object to be persisted. Console output for the above code excerpt is:

```
before -     parameterPojo.getId(): 399dc41d-54e8-41bf-a33f-d8e68422f2a2
before -  parameterPojo.getFtpId(): 7982daee-cf41-459c-85bf-1403004ecb20
before -  parameterPojo.getSqlId(): 74fd5116-cee6-4441-aa6d-af8f0501269c
before - parameterPojo.getSmtpId(): fc1bf5b9-4b54-4c03-a574-2fd2a4dd5ac2
after -     parameter.getId(): 9dfe60b0-dfed-40a5-b18c-97fe29f91feb
after -  parameter.getFtpId(): f4416b10-3d2f-43ee-a547-c69857db3ffb
after -  parameter.getSqlId(): 397dc48a-efd0-4cb5-b275-7b200c38a7c5
after - parameter.getSmtpId(): c4dd20de-630a-4e49-add4-41c40ba83de2
```

Ids are generated, for all entities, using this:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, length=64)
private String id;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
}
```

The method itself is:

```
protected Parameter populateParameterFromPojo(ParameterPojo parameterPojo) {

    Parameter parameter = parameterService.findById(parameterPojo.getId());
    FtpConnection ftpConnection = ftpService.findById(parameterPojo.getFtpId());
    SqlConnection sqlConnection = sqlService.findById(parameterPojo.getSqlId());
    SmtpConnection smtpConnection = smtpService.findById(parameterPojo.getSmtpId());

    ftpConnection.setId(parameterPojo.getFtpId());

    sqlConnection.setId(parameterPojo.getFtpId());

    smtpConnection.setId(parameterPojo.getSmtpId());

    parameter.setId(parameterPojo.getId());
    parameter.setDescription(parameterPojo.getDescription());
    parameter.setFtpConnection(ftpConnection);
    parameter.setSqlConnection(sqlConnection);
    parameter.setSmtpConnection(smtpConnection);
    parameter.setUuid(parameterPojo.getUuid());

    return parameter;
}
```

Though I'm enforcing the old ids via a `setId(String uuid)`, the resulting entity and its childs all get new ids.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As what I can see is that, your setter is creating a new UUID for you every time you call it.

```
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
}
```

Although you passed in your id, but your this.id = UUID.randomUUID which is creating a new UUID for you.

Your setter should be something like this to set the same id instead of creating a new one

```
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

Edit:
I would suggest you to allow your database table/ framework ID generator (for object) to default a UUID for new record, in that case you would not need to set ID to your object

If you insisted to include it, i would suggest either you create 2 setters, one with parameter, another without parameter

```
public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

public void setId() {
        this.id = //UUID generate
    }
```

Or check if ID passed in as parameter is null/ empty,

```
public void setId(string id) {
       //if id not equals null/ empty string
            this.id = id;

       // else
            this.id = //UUID generate
        }
```

Though, i prefer to let database to generate new UUID for new object (if possible)

Comment: won't this change prevent the creation of the random id?

Comment: isn't this about persisting the same id? so your setId will also be used on creation too?

Comment: I am not used to hibernate, but from what i see you are using annotation to allow object to auto-gen the UUID for you, you don't have to call a setter for new object, so you actually don't have to worry about UUID not generated for new object. Hope I get you right?

Comment: OK, buddy! Thanks! I'll try something different.

Answer (score 0):

Your setter method is setting the id to a random UUID

```
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
}
```

If you want to be able to set it change it to

```
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

Comment: I thought about that prior to posting this question and had tried before and after your suggestion. I decided to leave it as it was because I was unsure whether a new entity would get a random id setting if I left as per your correct suggestion. Also, after changing as per you suggestion, I get a `org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement`.

Comment: Can I ask you why, if you're using a generated ID, you want to still be able to set the ID yourself?

Comment: I assume secondly you're trying to persist this parameter pojo after this segment of code? That would account for the org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException as an entity already exists with that id as unique = true has been set on your id column

Comment: My approach to using a generated ID was to not using `Long` or `Integer` ids. What I thought about setting the ID was in order not to create a new object. Yes, the entity is persisted after the code segment.

Comment: Ok then what is happening here is that even if you've set your Id, when your DOA persists the entity, it is using the generator @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2") to give the entity a n id

Comment: thanks, mate! I have changed the id generating strategy to some that I did not wanted to use originally, but all is good now!